# Embedding views in tpl files

Tags: views, theming, performance

I need an advice. Is there any downsides when embedding views in the page/node tpl files like the following:

`<?php print views_embed_view('course_videos', 'block_1'); ?>` and this `<?php $key =  views_get_view_result('course_videos', 'block_2');  ?>` in the node.tpl files

I am little bit concerned cause I've read several articles saying you must not query the db or use a complex php logic in the tpl files. Everything's working like a charm now. The site is still not in production though...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Including views in tpl is going backwards. Drupal allows you to use views as pages and as blocks. You can apply templates to that pages and blocks, and you can put blocks in regions. By calling views from template, you are messing with theme registry and cache logic. It might be not an issue if site is small, and both read and write volumes are low, but it will result in pages being out of sync on heavy loaded site.

Instead of outputting view directly, make a region, output it in template file, and put a views block inside.

Using views_embed_view in a preprocess function in template.php might be OK. Opinions and experience with it can vary, and I would try to avoid it, but certainly it does not mess with cache or theme registry like using it in tpl would.

Comment: ok, but what if I get a view in the template.php preprocess function and pass it to the tpl file like a variable, like the following: 

In the template.php $variables['views_course_videos'] = views_embed_view('course_videos', 'block');

In the tpl file:
print $'views_course_videos';

Is this way ok?

Comment: @IvanIvanov Not really. Templates should not generate errors if view is unavailable for some reason. It can lead to long, long hours of frustrating debugging. Been there, done that, never again.

Comment: Got your point :) Thank you for sharing your experience!

Comment: @Mołot Gotta say I disagree - using `views_embed_view` in a preprocess function in template.php is pretty standard (obviously not if you're trying to build a totally de-coupled theme, but for custom project-specific themes I've seen it quite a bit)

Comment: @Clive well, that's why I'm not including it in my answer. but I had a bad experience with it, sharing when asked.

Comment: I'll second that in preprocess, setting a variable to the output of a views hook is pretty widespread as well but totally agree it should be kept out of the actual tpls.

Comment: I hope @IvanIvanov will read your comments too, and make his own decision as consciously as possible. Maybe one day I'll feel a need to try it again and change my mind? Not happening soon, but who knows ;)

Comment: @Mołot You're definitely right from a best practice point of view - separate logic and display as much as possible. The natural tendency (for me anyway) is to look at even Drupal from an MVC point of view, even though it's anything but. Sometimes "who's the controller?" gets a bit muddy, and inevitably someone's gonna use the theme layer at some point!

Comment: @Clive updated my answer. I hope it's as factual as feasible now, and opinions may sit in comments. I've seen it work OK and I've spent long hours when it didn't. In ideal world... ;)