# Include current node in Views

Tags: 7, views

I am displaying a Slideshow on each node. I want to display image of current node on start of slideshow. Then other images related to that node.

I added a taxonomy field in content type. I get the top 10 nodes related to tags selected in content. I displayed the views using views_embed_view in node.tpl.php

How to include current node image with in the views?

Comment: And how do you manage relations between nodes? How have you built your view? How do you attach view to node (there are at the very least 3 ways to do it)?

Comment: Updated my question. And I displayed the views using `views_embed_view` in node.tpl.php

Comment: [Here is an explanation](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/85345/16495) why I cannot really help you. I *avoided* having any experience with this way of embedding views, and I plan to avoid it in future. Are you open for some refactoring?